# Can I install Ubuntu on my laptop?

Tags: windows, hp, hp-pavilion

I have a hp pavilion g6 laptop, it runs Windows 8.1.
I was planning to use a free os for a while.
Which is the recommended Ubuntu version for me? I am totally a newbie to such OS.
I have only used windows till date.

Comment: yes you can install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do to find it out, it's to try it.

Download, burn and load from an ubuntu iso image. Instructions can be found here: [How to create a bootable USB stick
on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)
Also about installing it, you should read some little more documentation: [Install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) and [WindowsDualBoot manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

About the version, you definitely will want to go for ubuntu 14.04 64-bits.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32bit or 64bit if your processor will support it.

You can burn a bootable CD with the OS first off and try out the OS without committing yourself to it initially then, if it works (as it should!) then commit either by loading alongside Win8 or replacing the OS entirely.